# SQL Query for Custom Post Type and Multiple Custom Fields

Tags: sql, wordpress

I am using [WP Data Tables](http://themes.karaliki.ru/wpdatatables/custom-demo-list-wordpress-pages/) to create a table from the SQL DB. In the wordpress backend the example code to use looked like this:

```
SELECT post_id, post_date
FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_type =  'custom_post_type'
AND post_status =  'publish'
```

Im trying to get custom field values from the post meta. Here is what I have so far...

```
SELECT post_id, post_date
FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_type =  'custom_post_type'
AND post_status =  'publish'
AND SELECT custom_field_key_1, custom_field_key_2, custom_field_key_3
FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE post_id = post_id
```

UPDATE:

I found that p.ID was needed instead of post_id and that I need search for the meta_key. Something like...

```
SELECT p.post_title, 
       p.post_date,
       pm.meta_key = 'custom_field_key'
FROM wp_posts p 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta pm 
ON p.ID = pm.post_id
WHERE p.post_type = 'custom_post_type'
AND p.post_status = 'publish'
```

Comment: I believe you need `JOIN` here.

Answer (score 4):

Use an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT p.post_id, 
       p.post_date, 
       pm.custom_field_key_1, 
       pm.custom_field_key_2, 
       pm.custom_field_key_3
FROM wp_posts p 
   INNER JOIN wp_postmeta pm 
       ON p.post_id = pm.post_id
WHERE p.post_type = 'custom_post_type'
   AND p.post_status = 'publish'
```

Comment: @user2106176 -- glad this helped.  Looking at your update, I think you need to move "pm.meta_key = 'custom_field_key'" to your WHERE clause.  You can't set a field value in your SELECT statement.  Best of luck!

Comment: I know this answer is too old but it's now working with custom_field_key

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that standard SQL is supported you will need something like this (untested):

```
SELECT w.post_id, w.post_date, m.custom_field_key_1, m.custom_field_key_2, m.custom_field_key_3
FROM wp_posts w, wp_postmeta m
WHERE post_type =  'custom_post_type' AND post_status =  'publish'
AND w.post.id = m.post.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
SELECT p.post_id, p.post_date,
    pm.custom_field_key_1, pm.custom_field_key_2, pm.custom_field_key_3
FROM wp_posts p
JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON p.post_id = pm.post_id
WHERE p.post_type =  'custom_post_type'
AND p.post_status =  'publish'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok even though you updated an answer. I took your example and I worked this out:

```
SELECT p.ID, 
       p.post_title, 
       pm.meta_value as 'value1', 
       pma.meta_value as 'value2'

FROM  wp_posts p 
      INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm  ON pm.post_id  = p.ID
      INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS pma ON pma.post_id = p.ID

WHERE
      pma.meta_key = 'custom_field_key_1' AND
      pm.meta_key = 'custom_field_key_2' AND

      p.post_type = 'your_post_type' AND 
      p.post_status = 'publish'
```

So here I am using alias `AS` for values hosted in the same table, `INNER JOIN` for `wp_postmeta` and `post_id`  and that's all.

References:
[Multiple Inner join same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370437/multiple-inner-join-from-the-same-table)

By doing this you will get an array with posts and your selected custom fields:

```
array(1) {
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#341 (4) {
          ["ID"]=>    string(1) "1123"
          ["post_title"]=>  string(15) "Your post title"
          ["custom_field_key_1"]=> string(12) "Your value 1 "
          ["custom_field_key_2"]=> string(29) "Your value 2"
}
```

You can add as many alias and meta_key as you need. Hope this help!